# Como retornar o numero entidades de uma tabela usando JPA e a função COUNT?

Tags: java, query, jpa, persistência

Estou usando a implementação EclipseLink e não  consigo resolver a seguinte `query` que deve estar errada:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e , COUNT(*) FROM Empregado e"); 
Integer resultado =  (Integer) query.getSingleResult();
```

Minhas `entyties` são:

```
public class Empregado implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Telefone telefone;
    .... getters and setters
```

E essa:

```
@Entity
public class Telefone {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;    
    private String numero;
    private String tipo;
    .... getters and setters
```

Ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An
>   exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager:
>       Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT e , COUNT(*) FROM Empregado e]. 
>       [16, 16] The left expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
>       [17, 17] The right expression is missing from the arithmetic expression

Gostaria de saber se possível como fazer a `query` anterior  e também como conseguir o mesmo resultado usando as novas características do  **JPA 2.1** as famosas `Stored Procedure Query`.

Já pesquisei e encontrei uns exemplos que recebiam um parâmetro para a função mas no meu caso e não passo nem um parâmetro apenas quero o resultado!

Aqui esta o [*link* em inglês](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/call-stored-procedures-jpa-part-2/) do exemplo, que recebe um parâmetro no procedimento armazenado.

Comment: Qual erro está tendo? Tenta assim: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Empregado e`

Comment: Já tentei isso!Não deu certo , o jpa não reconhece o *

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
 "SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Empregados e"
```

Fonte: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JPA/4510__JPA_Query_COUNT.htm

Comment: valeu pela atenção.Nesse link o cara não esta usando o Spring Framework? Isso não faz diferença? Eu estou usando o EclipseeLink

Comment: @PenaPintada Como você está usando JPA, o EclipseLink vai utilizar a sintaxe do JPQL, e este comando do Celso está correto de acordo com a [wiki do EclipseLink](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL)

Comment: @Julian! Valeu , mas mesmo assim , infelizmente ,não consigo o resultado. O amigo não poderia implementar essas duas pequenas classes  e ver se funciona?

Comment: Depois de implementar a solução do Celso qual o erro que você recebe?

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade o tipo de retorno não é `Integer` e sim `Long`
Aqui esta a consulta:

```
String consulta = "SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Empregado e";
        TypedQuery<Long> query = em.createQuery(consulta, Long.class);
        Long resultado = query.getSingleResult();

        System.out.println(resultado);
```